# lightning:datatable - is it possible to add multiple urls on a single cell?

Tags: lightning

Using Lightning:datatable, is it possible to set different examples of a record(for example 5 accounts), and make those 5 accounts redirectable to the record page layout?

Let's say I have a column called "Account Examples", I want to make those examples clickable, I know you can do it for a single record by changing the column type to "URL", is it possible to achieve the same with multiple records in a single cell?

Comment: Give a look at [enter link description here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/263662/69041) Hope that is helpful. Thanks