# LWC: create hyperlink to the related opportunity record

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, aura, opportunity, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a created a lightning web component (lwc) that displays related opportunity records. I want to create a hyperlink on the opportunity name so when the user clicks on the name, it should take the user to the opportunity record page.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <template if:true={oppList}>
         <lightning-datatable
                 key-field="id"
                 data={oppList}
                 show-row-number-column
                 row-number-offset={rowOffset}
                 hide-checkbox-column
                 columns={columns}>
         </lightning-datatable>
    </template>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getOpportunities from '@salesforce/apex/TT_DisplayRelatedOpportunities.getOppList';


export default class DisplayRelatedOpportunities extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;

    @track columns = [
        { label: 'Opportunity Name', fieldName: 'Name' }
    ];
   @track oppList;

   //Method 2
   @wire (getOpportunities, { recordId: '$recordId'}) wiredOpportunities({data,error}){
        if (data) {
             this.oppList = data;
        console.log(data); 
        } else if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        }
   }
}
```

Apex:

```
public with sharing class TT_DisplayRelatedOpportunities {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Opportunity> getOppList(String recordId) {
        return [
            SELECT Name
            FROM Opportunity
            WHERE LOT__c =: recordId OR Lot_2__c =: recordId
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257065/hyperlink-record-name-lwc-datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the URL type into the columns for the name. Also, you need to process data that comes from the apex and add the new key value to existing data. The new key and value should be `nameUrl = '/${row.Id}';` this.

Here is the updated code:

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class TT_DisplayRelatedOpportunities {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Opportunity> getOppList(String recordId) {
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE LOT__c = :recordId OR Lot_2__c = :recordId];
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <template if:true={oppList}>
         <lightning-datatable
                 key-field="Id"
                 data={oppList}
                 show-row-number-column
                 row-number-offset={rowOffset}
                 hide-checkbox-column
                 columns={columns}>
         </lightning-datatable>
    </template>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getOpportunities from '@salesforce/apex/TT_DisplayRelatedOpportunities.getOppList';


export default class DisplayRelatedOpportunities extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;

    @track columns = [
        {
            label: 'Opportunity Name',
            fieldName: 'nameUrl',
            type: 'url',
            typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'name' }, 
            target: '_blank'},
            sortable: true
        }
    ];

    @track error;
    @track oppList = [];   

   @wire(getOpportunities, { recordId: '$recordId'})
    wiredOpportunities(result) {
        const { data, error } = result;
        if(data) {
            let nameUrl;
            this.oppList = data.map(row => { 
                nameUrl = `/${row.Id}`;
                return {...row , nameUrl} 
            })
            this.error = undefined;
        }
        if(error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.oppList = [];
        }
    }
}
```