# Unable to create URL with NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl

Tags: lightning-web-components, hyperlink

LWC - HTML - PARENT

```
        <div class="slds-page-header__col-details">
            <ul class="slds-page-header__detail-row">
                <template if:true={hKeyFields}>
                    <template for:each={hKeyFields} for:item="field">
                        <li class="slds-page-header__detail-block" key={field.apiName}>
                            <div class="slds-text-title slds-truncate" title={field.label}>
                                <span>{field.label}</span>
                                <template if:true={field.object.inlineHelpText}>
                                    <lightning-helptext content={field.object.inlineHelpText}></lightning-helptext>
                                </template>
                            </div>
                            <template if:false={field.object.reference}>
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title={field.record.displayValue}>{field.record.displayValue}</div>
                            </template>
                            <template if:true={field.object.reference}>
                                <c-relationship-link target-object-api={field.reference.value.apiName} target-label={field.reference.displayValue} target-id={field.reference.value.id} ></c-hl-relationship-link>
                            </template>
                        </li>
                    </template>
                </template>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

LWC - HTML - CHILD

```
<template>
    <a href={url} onclick={viewRecord} title={targetLabel}>{targetLabel}</a>
</template>
```

LWC - JS - CHILD

```
import { LightningElement, api, track} from 'lwc'; 
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
export default class RelationshipLink extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api targetId;
    @api targetLabel;
    @api targetObjectApi;
    @track url;
    connectedCallback() {
        //LL20190513 - Generate URL for viewing record page
        this.relationshipRef = {
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.targetId,
                objectApiName: this.targetObjectApi,
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        };
        this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl](this.relationshipRef)
            .then((url) => {
                this.url = url;
            });
    }
    viewRecord(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](this.relationshipRef);
    }
}
```

### **Following solutions mentioned below and no luck:**

[Lightning Web Component - Navigation - Show Link in a List / Table to
Open Record solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/255708/lightning-web-component-navigation-show-link-in-a-list-table-to-open-recor) posted by @glls

### Also note the Chrome console shows this:

aura_proddebug.js:237 [LWC warning]: Invalid event type
"WireContextEvent" dispatched in element .
Event name should only contain lowercase alphanumeric characters.

### Output HTML

[image]

### Chrome Debug Isolated

[image]

Comment: The resulting links don't work. Showing an image of the output html above.

Comment: Apologies @glls, if you see above updated my post to show the resulting html. Clicking on the link does not resolve to a valid hyperlink, just what you see in the screenshot of the output HTML, which does not navigate to the expected related record.

Comment: Yes the GenerateUrl promise seems to be the issue, but can't be certain. Not familiar enough with the NavigationMixin behavior. Screenshot above.

Comment: check the targetId and targetObjectApi

Comment: Outputted them on the page in parallel to the <a> tag and they both attributes show correct values. Debugged in console and they seem to be assigned properly to pageref attributes.

Comment: IMO seems to be an issue with the GenerateUrl Promise, "url" is returning null, despite a healthy PageRef object being passed in. The resulting console message show in the post above "Invalid event type "WireContextEvent..." is also suspicious as I isolated it as a direct result of the NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl method being fired. Haven't found any KB items on that. Also thought this might be a data binding issue one-way vs two-way. Stumped at this point.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here seems to be that NavigationMixin didn't support 15-Id, only 18-Id.