# Navigate to records returned by apex class by clicking on them in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am new to Lightning Web Components. I have made a component that searches contacts. I displayed recordId, name and email of the contacts. I have placed the component on the lead record page. I want to navigate to a particular contact by clicking on it from the result obtained.

I prepared a lightning card for each displayed contact and implemented an onClick method. In onclick method, I used `this.recordId` for navigation. It's taking me to the lead record page again. How can I use the `contactId` to navigate to the contact record page by clicking on the respective card? I searched for solution but didn't find any.

[image: Search Contacts]

Apex Method:

```
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        public static list<sObject> getContactList(String name){
            String key = '%'+name+'%';
            String query = 'Select Id,Name,Email,Phone From Contact Where Name LIKE :key LIMIT 10';
            return Database.query(query);
        }
```

HTML File:

```html
        <template>
            <lightning-card >
                    <div class="slds-m-around_medium"><h1>Search Contacts(communicate with apex)</h1></div>
                    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                        <lightning-input  label="Find Contact" value={searchKey} onchange={handleChange} class="slds-m-bottom_small">
                        </lightning-input>
                        <template for:each={contacts} for:item="contact">                   
                            <lightning-layout-item key={contact.key}>
                                <lightning-card onclick={navigateToContact} variant="narrow">
                                    <c-contact-card slot="footer" key={contact.id} contact1={contact} ></c-contact-card>
                                    <!-- the above component is used for printing id, name and email -->
                                </lightning-card>
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                        </template>
                    </div>
             </lightning-card>
        </template>
```

JS Function:

```js
    navigateToContact() {
        // View a custom object record.
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.recordId,
                objectApiName: 'contact', // objectApiName is optional
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar question being answered on this link with the answers : [Lightning Web Component - Navigation - Show Link in a List / Table to Open Record](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/255708/38191).

My recommended solution is to create a component just to display the link then it can be used globally for any object. For your case you can do :

```
<c-navigation-link label="View Contact" label ="" title=""                      
    type="standard__recordPage" record-id="Contact.Id">
</c-navigation-link>
```

Comment: I used a button  
`<lightning-button key={contact.Id} label={contact.Name} title="View Contact" onclick={navigateToContact} value={contact.Id}></lightning-button>`  
and changed JS to  
`recordId: event.target.value,`  
 It works!  
But following change does not work  
`<lightning-card key={contact.Id} value={contact.Id} onclick={navigateToContact}>`  
 It gives "Page Does Not Exist" error

Comment: Try with a hardcoded contact record id first to see if it is working.
And I think you are missing <template  for:each={contacts.data} for:item="contact">