# Lightning Web Components - Why does my nested component need a key?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a LWC that includes a table where I am using a `for:each` directive to iterate over my dataset and create the rows for my table, with each row having the item Id as the unique key:

```
<table>
  <template for:each={list} for:item={item}>
    <tr key={item.Id}>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</table>
```

The above worked fine.

I am now trying to use a custom component to replace some of the `<td>` elements that have special behaviour.

```
<table>
  <template for:each={list} for:item={item}>
    <tr key={item.Id}>
      <c-my-custom-table-cell></c-my-custom-table-cell>
      <c-my-custom-table-cell></c-my-custom-table-cell>
      <c-my-custom-table-cell></c-my-custom-table-cell>
    </tr>
  </template>
</table>
```

The issue is, when I add my custom element to replace the `td`, I get a *Missing key for element* error message saying that elements inside an iterator need a unique key.

**Update**

I've tried a simplified version of my custom table cell:

```
<template>
  <div>TEST</div>
</template>
```

with css of:

```
:host {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

However, I have already applied the key to the `tr` element. Why am I being asked for it again?

**Further Update**
In order to be able to use my custom table cells, I also needed to create a custom component for the table row:

css:

```
:host {
  display: table-row;
}
```

then I could get everything to work together:

```
<table>
  <template for:each={list} for:item={item}>
    <c-custom-row key={item.Id}>
      <c-custom-cell value={item.Name}></c-custom-cell>
      <c-custom-cell value={item.StartDate__c}></c-custom-cell>
      <c-custom-cell value={item.EndDate__c}></c-custom-cell>
    </c-custom-row>
  </template>
</table>
```

Comment: you should not have tr as you are already mentioning table-row in CSS. And it should not be table-cell. What you are doing is table-row

Comment: Hi. Perhaps I haven't made myself clear, but it *is* the table cell (`td`) that I wanted to be custom, and not the table row. I will change the above example so that you can see multiple custom table cells in a row.

Comment: pls check my modified answer. pls let me know if it still does not solve

Answer (score 4):

I've just had similar issue like 30 minutes ago and I found [this topic](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251100/lightning-web-component-for-table-rows-and-cells?noredirect=1&lq=1). Basically what you need to do is add

```
:host {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

to your child component and remove surrounding `<td>` if you have one.

---

Also add `key` attribute to your `c-my-custom-table-cell`:

```
<table>
    <template for:each={list} for:item={item}>
        <c-my-custom-table-cell key={item.Id}></c-my-custom-table-cell>
    </template>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Bartosz. Did you get this to work for you? I've tried this out, and I'm still getting the same error. I'm doing what sfdcfox suggests, adding the css and *not* including the `td`.

Comment: Yes I did. Can you paste add your `c-my-custom-table-cell` code?

Comment: Thanks. I've tried just the most basic version I could. I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: I updated my answer. Basically you need to always use `key` on first element in iteration

Comment: Thanks Bartosz. It is the table row I am iterating over, though, not the table cell. Your answer helped me to find a solution, though. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Important**

> You need custom component to `act` as table-cell only when table is generic
>   component and number of rows is decided at run-time. Or else you can just use the custom component inside `td`
>   which works absolutely fine.

**ADDED BASED ON COMMENTS**

If you need each cell to be custom, you just need below in `tbody`:

```
<tbody>
            <template for:each={list} for:item="item">
                <tr key={item.Id}>
                    <td>
                        <c-poc-cell cell-value={item.name}></c-poc-cell>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <c-poc-cell cell-value={item.type}></c-poc-cell>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </tbody>
```

and the cell template:

```
<template> {cellValue} </template>
```

You need to define `@api cellValue` in JS

---

**For having custom component act as `tr`**

You should not have `tr`. here is the example:

parent comp:

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-theme_default">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td> Name </td>
                    <td> Type </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <template for:each={list} for:item="item">
                    <c-poc-row key={item.Id} rec={item}></c-poc-row>
                </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
```

And in JS, the `list`:

```
connectedCallback() {
    this.list = [
        { Id: '1', name: 'qwe', type: 't1' },
        { Id: '2', name: 'we', type: 't2' },
        { Id: '3', name: 'rrr', type: 't3' }
    ];
}
```

Now the `tr` component:

```
<template>
    <td>{rec.name}</td>
    <td>{rec.type}</td>
</template>
```

and its JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class PocRow extends LightningElement {
    @api rec = {};
}
```

and its CSS:

```
:host {
    display: table-row;
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I am creating a custom table cell, not a custom table row. My understanding from what @sfdcfox said in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251100/lightning-web-component-for-table-rows-and-cells?noredirect=1&lq=1 is that I can replace the `td` if I want.

Comment: Any clue why  `c-poc-row` does need a key?

Comment: added in answer for custom cell

Comment: My idea is if not needed for react so should also be not needed in LWC as both are web framework.
https://codepen.io/pranayjaiswal/pen/YmOpjo

Comment: @PranayJaiswal. `template for:each` is native to LWC and it does lot of calculations based on `key`. I checked this in console debug.

Comment: Thanks Salesforce-Sas. Your answer helped me to find a solution.