# LWC displaying data using tables

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am creating a Standard table but it did not work. After some search, i tried to implement this solution [Lightning Web Component for table rows and cells](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251100/lightning-web-component-for-table-rows-and-cells?noredirect=1&lq=1)
but always the key is throwing error.

here is the JS error.

> Error: [LWC error]: Invalid "key" attribute value in
>   "" in [object:vm undefined (191)] for item number 0.
>   Set a unique "key" value on all iterated child elements.

Parentcomp.html

```
 <template if:true={alltraffic.data}>                
 <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-border_left slds- 
 border_right" >
 <thead>
  <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
    <th class="" scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate"  title="Type">Type</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <template for:each={alltraffic.data} for:item="traffic">
         <c-traffic-data key={traffic}></c-traffic-data>
    </template>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </template>
```

trafficData.html

```
   <template>
    <th data-label="Type" scope="row">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title={row.Type}>{row.Type}</div>
    </th>
    <td data-label="Monday">
        <div class="slds-truncate">
            <p>{row.Monday}</p>
        </div>
    </td>
    </template>
```

trafficData.css

```
:host {
   display: table-row;
 }
```

Comment: If you are posting a question about an error, **please always include the complete text of the error and its location**. We can't run your code in many situations; we need you to **help us help you** by providing all of the relevant details. Please take some time to read [ask] to learn about this site's expectations.

Comment: You should make an [edit] to the body of your post to include this information.

Comment: Added the error message to the question.

Answer (score 1):

For the "key", you'll need to use a unique property from the object you are iterating... you can't use the object itself.  (IOW: Use `c-traffic-data key={traffic.Type}` instead of `{traffic}` [as long as "Type" is unique to each row])

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_lists

> Every item in a list must have a key. When a list changes, the
>   framework uses the key to identify each item so that it can rerender
>   only the item that changed. The key must be a string or a number, it
>   can't be an object. You can’t use index as a value for key. Assign
>   unique keys to an incoming data set. To add new items to a data set,
>   use a private property to track and generate keys.