Create a custom data type for lightning tree grid LWC
I am planning to use the Lightning Tree Grid component in my LWC. But there are a few columns which are to be represented differently than the standard types available.
Now it is possible to create custom data types for Lightning Datatable by extending the datatable class: Create a Custom Data Type. And since the tree grid is based on this, is it possible to do the same to create custom types for the tree grid component. I did search online, but wasn't able to find any resources regarding this. Any help is appreciated.

I am not exactly sure, if you could extend the tree grid and modify it like the LightningDatatable. However, you could build your own table with tree grid, the way you like by following the blueprint here: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tree-grid/

here are a couple of simple implementations of custom tree-grid based on existing styles
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289272/lwc-custom-tree-grid-issue/289472#289472

as you can see the default behaviour is done on setting ariaLevel and ariaExpanded value on rows, which I think it's not possible with current support for custom lightning datatable, so I think you need fully custom component
